# how to stub a post request with the required response in rails minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to stub a post request with the below response

```
{ 'data' => {
  'detections' =>
      [
        [{
          'language' => 'en',
          'isReliable' => false,
          'confidence' => 0.134
        }],
        [{
          'language' => 'ar',
          'isReliable' => false,
          'confidence' => 0.9882
        }]
      ]
} }
```

Can anyone help

Comment: See [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock).

Comment: I tried it returns only string but I need hash response

Comment: Keep looking there. Read the README.

Answer (score 0):

You can use webmock https://github.com/bblimke/webmock#stubbing-requests-based-on-method-uri-body-and-headers

```
response = { 'data' => {'detections' =>[[{'language' => 'en','isReliable'=>false,'confidence' => 0.134}],[{'language' => 'ar','isReliable' => false,'confidence' => 0.9882 }]]}}

stub_request(:post, "url").with(<if needed>).to_return(status: 201, body: response.to_json, headers: { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
```